# how to display array data in table formate in php using foreach

Tags: php

We have an array data.

```
Array
(
    [39] => Array
        (
            [20170125] => Array
                (
                    [1000] => Array
                        (
                            [click] => 1129
                            [AFF_NAME] => EMAIL[1000]
                            [AFF_ACTIVATION] => 1
                            [CR_PER_CLICK_AFF] => 0%
                        )

                [1001] => Array
                    (
                        [click] => 59
                        [AFF_NAME] => SMS_Promotions[1001]
                        [AFF_ACTIVATION] => 0
                        [CR_PER_CLICK_AFF] => 0%
                    )
    )

[20170124] => Array
            (
                [1000] => Array
                    (
                        [click] => 1129
                        [AFF_NAME] => EMAIL[1000]
                        [AFF_ACTIVATION] => 1
                        [CR_PER_CLICK_AFF] => 0%
                    )

                [1001] => Array
                    (
                        [click] => 59
                        [AFF_NAME] => SMS_Promotions[1001]
                        [AFF_ACTIVATION] => 0
                        [CR_PER_CLICK_AFF] => 0%
                    )
    )

)
[56] => Array
        (
            [20170125] => Array
                (
                    [1000] => Array
                        (
                            [click] => 1129
                            [AFF_NAME] => EMAIL[1000]
                            [AFF_ACTIVATION] => 1
                            [CR_PER_CLICK_AFF] => 0%
                        )

                    [1001] => Array
                        (
                            [click] => 59
                            [AFF_NAME] => SMS_Promotions[1001]
                            [AFF_ACTIVATION] => 0
                            [CR_PER_CLICK_AFF] => 0%
                        )
        )
 [20170124] => Array
            (
                [1000] => Array
                    (
                        [click] => 1129
                        [AFF_NAME] => EMAIL[1000]
                        [AFF_ACTIVATION] => 1
                        [CR_PER_CLICK_AFF] => 0%
                    )

                [1001] => Array
                    (
                        [click] => 59
                        [AFF_NAME] => SMS_Promotions[1001]
                        [AFF_ACTIVATION] => 0
                        [CR_PER_CLICK_AFF] => 0%
                    )
    )

)
```

)

I want to display this array in below table format using php foreach, can anyone help?

> |--------|---------------|------------------------|--------------------------|---------------|------------------------|--------------------------|
>       |AFF_NAME|20170125(click)|20170125(AFF_ACTIVATION)|20170125(CR_PER_CLICK_AFF)|20170124(click)|20170124(AFF_ACTIVATION)|20170124(CR_PER_CLICK_AFF)|
>       |--------|---------------|------------------------|--------------------------|---------------|------------------------|--------------------------|
>       |EMAIL(1000)|1129|1|0%|59|0|0%|
>       |--------|---------------|------------------------|--------------------------|---------------|------------------------|--------------------------|
>       |SMS_Promotions(1001)|1129|1|0%|59|0|0%|
>       |--------|---------------|------------------------|--------------------------|---------------|------------------------|--------------------------|

Comment: yikes.. fix your posting. Make it look easy to read. You can do this by clicking the "edit" link

Comment: i see your array.. but i dont see your php code? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

**use 2 for each**

```
  <?php  foreach ($array1 as $arrray =>$value){
                 foreach ($value as $abc => $value2){ ?>
      <tr>
  <td> <?php echo $value2['click']; ?></td>
        <td> all otheres</td>
  </tr>
  <?php  }
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to rome...

```
$collector=array();
//flatten your array struct,  take datetime from first level and id from second
foreach($array as $date => $set){
  foreach($set as $aff_id => $subset){
    //bind datetime
    $subset['DATE'] = $date;
    //bind id
    $subset['AFF_ID'] = $aff_id;
    //sort by key to generate an valid table later
    ksort($subset);
    //collect it
    $collector[]=$subset;
  }
}

//create header
$table = "<table><tr><th>".implode('</th><th>',array_keys($collector[0]))."</th></tr>";
//create rows
foreach($collector as $set){
   $table .= "<tr><td>".implode('</td><td>',$set)."</td></tr>";
}
$table .= "</table>";
//output
print $table;
```

Change the code if needed.